# Exclude class from resulting dex file

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, dex

I have a problem. I have a structure of project looking like this:
P
|-SubP1
|-SubP2

There are two stub classes **android.media.IRemoteDisplay** in both packages. They differ in implementation, but that's not the matter - they will be replaced by system classes when I'll run the app on Android.

However, there is a problem - I can't build the project because dexMerger fails - it says there are two conflicting classes. I can understand that error - after all, there are really two conflicting classes :)

But when I try to exclude these files in build.gradle like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
            exclude '**/android/media/**'
        }
    }
}
```

The compilation fails because it can't find **android.media.IRemoteControlDisplay** class(and it's nested classes).

How can I still use these classes, but exclude them from resulting DEX file?

Please **DON'T** question if it's right to exclude the class from compiled project - it's the right thing to do, I already did it, but manually - by pre-compiling SubP1 and SubP2 to jars and then manually removing IRemoteController.class from these jar files and then including those jars in P.

I'll also be satisfied with that solution:
1. Build SubP1
2. Remove IRemoteControlDisplay.class from SubP1.jar
3. Build SubP2
4. Remove IRemoteControlDisplay.class from SubP2.jar
5. Add SubP1.jar and SubP2.jar as dependencies to P
6. Build P
If that's possible, please let me know.

Comment: If you don't include it in DEX you app is gonna force close because it won't find the class it wants to use.

Comment: why are you excluding the whole folder and not just that particular class/file?

Comment: Eugen, I know what I'm doing. The app won't force crash because IRemoteControlDisplay is a class that is present on system package android.media. You normally can't gain access to it, but I need to access it, and I did it by creating stub class with same method signatures. So, by excluding it, the app will make calls to system implementation. BTW, I already did it - compiling the jars and deleting .class files from there and then including those jars in the project. But now I want to keep it more automatic.

Comment: Jim, because in my project this whole package contains only one file, so it's the same :)

Comment: if it's only one file, why is your error saying that a different file is missing? How could it exclude any other file if the directory only has one file in it?

Comment: I've done this sort of thing before. In your edit you remove the AIDL file from both jars. you should be able to do a build with only 1 included - it doesn't matter which one as long as it defines the methods and properties you intend to use at runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I've been able to do it.

What I needed was a *runtime* dependency instead of *compilation-time* dependency. So, I've created submodule for SubP1 called SubSubP1(for example) moved the android.media.IRemoteDisplay into the SubSubP1, and created submodule SubSubP2 for SubP2, and did the same with stub class. Then I've declared the dependency as following for SubP1 and SubP2:

```
dependencies {
    provided project(':SubP1:SubSubP1')
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    provided project(':SubP2:SubSubP2')
}
```

And that did the trick! Instead of compiling the classes, Gradle assumed that they will be loaded at runtime.